# PHP SOAP CLIENT enable

Tags: php, soap-client

I want to use Soap client in my localhost 
I edited my php.ini and removed ; from the extention but when I run my code the wrong 
Fatal error: Class 'SoapClient' not found in C:\AppServ\www\portal\captiveportal-tc.php on line 41
when I open my phpinfo.php 
I see soap 
how can I solve it

Comment: There are different php.ini files, one for cgi, one for cli, one for fpm, and so on. Have you changed all files? Or do do "run" your code by calling it via a webpage, like you did with phpinfo?

Comment: I don't know I edited the php.ini file which I found in start menue

Comment: After changing the php.ini file, you have to restart your web service (ex. Apache). If you done that, check your web service error log file for any error during the service startup.